# Search for Hardcoded String in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How could I get all hardcoded string in Flutter?

In Android I can get it by Lint Inspection but is there any similar to that in Flutter?

I opened an issue on Flutter Repo:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42227

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: @Doc search for HardcodedText in Android lint
http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

Answer (score 7):

If you're on IntelliJ, you can find all text matching a hardcoded String regex.

1. Press `Cmd + Shift + F` (or `Ctrl + Shift + F`)
2. Enable regex search
3. Search for `"(.*?)"` or `'(.*?)'` depending on whether you use double-quotes or single-quotes for hardcoded strings. For both, use `"(.*?)"|'(.*?)'`
4. Step 3 would only show a maximum of 100 results
5. Press "Open in Find Window"

[image: Steps 2-5]

This should open a new Find window from the bottom with all results (3,144 in my case):

[image: Search-results-collapsed]

You can then expand the results directory and preview any hardcoded string in any file from the results:

[image]

Comment: it is good as a start, but it includes imports and json decoding which is not a text that need to be translated

Comment: You could play around with the regex so that it doesn't include imports. But I agree, this is not a perfect solution when wanting to implement localization. In my case, all hardcoded texts use double quotes. Since imports use single quotes, it makes my life a bit easier.

Comment: Regexp that excludes imports is `(?<!import )'(.*?)'`

Answer (score 3):

Use this Regex which is valid for both single and double quotes.

Exclude `import` statement.

```
(?<!import )("|')(.*?)\1
```

Exclude both `import` and `export`

```
(?<!(import|export) )("|')(.*?)\2
```

Exclude `import`, `export` and `part`

```
(?<!(import|export|part) )("|')(.*?)\2
```

Answer (score 1):

ignoring imports, map[' '], and json[' '] expressions, you can use a negative look behind to exclude certain patterns.

version 1
it only finds the hardcoded string and ignores the imports

```
(?:(?<!\bimport\s)(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'))|(?:\{"|\'\[)
```

version 2
it has the capability to find and ignore map JSON and import surround strings

```
(?<!import\s|map\['.*'\]|json\['.*'\]|R\..*\.)\"([^\"\\]*(\\.[^\"\\]*)*)\"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows and vsCode you can Click Ctrl-Shift+F then copy this **(?<!import)'(.*?)'** and paste it into your search field then include files with .dart extention